# encryption decryption

Tags: encryption

I am trying to create a custom encryption/decryption code in python. I read few articles and found that I can store the encryption ciphers in the dictionary. I tried using it but it is not working. keys will be letters in alphabetical order(A-Z) and values will be the letters that I want to put(ciphers). There is no specifics shift pattern in the encryption cipher. There are also numbers(0-9) in the encryption-decryption. they are in sequence though.

```
  dict = {'A' : 'O', 'B' : 'P', 'C' : 'J' ......'Z' : 'Z', ....
'0' : 9, '1' : 8, ............'8' : 1, '9' : 0}
```

These encrypted password will be stored in a database. I need help to create the code to encrypt and decrypt the password. If there's any other method to start with please let me know.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask] and try to ask a *specific* question. If you are just generally trying to *design a program* from scratch, then that is off-topic for Stack Overflow; you want to look for an actual *discussion forum*, which Stack Overflow is not.

Comment: Are you doing this because it's an assignment for a class you're taking, or because you actually want to cryptographically protect something? If you actually want to protect something, don't roll your own encryption.

Comment: Trying to roll your own encryption is like trying to do your own open heart surgery, but even trickier. Even experts have a very hard time getting it right.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use the Python [Cryptography Module](https://pypi.org/project/cryptography/)...
Here's some code that may help:

> I'm replacing your `dict` with the name `en_dict`

```py
#unencrypted_item should be a string
def encrypt(unencrypted_item):
    result = ""
    for i in unencrypted_item:
        result+=en_dict[i]
    return result

def encrypt(encrypted_item):
    result = ""
    for i in encrypted_item:
        for n in en_dict:
            if en_dict[n] == i:
                result += n
                break
    return result
```

Answer (score 1):

Try mapping the original string with the keys in your dictionary.

```py
mapping = {'A':'Z', 'B':'C', '1':'0', '2':'7'}
reverse_mapping = dict((j,i) for i,j in mapping.items())

string_to_encrypt = 'AB1'

encrypted_string = ''.join(map(mapping.__getitem__, string_to_encrypt))
print(encrypted_string) #ZC0

decrypted_string = ''.join(map(reverse_mapping.__getitem__, encrypted_string))
print(decrypted_string) #AB1
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, I hope that you plan to use your encryption scheme for academic purposes only because this simple substitution cipher is very insecure. For the most basic level of security you should look at storing salted hashes of user passwords instead, or use something like [`bcrypt`](https://pypi.org/project/bcrypt/).

WRT to your specific question, use your mapping dictionary with [`str.translate()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.translate) to translate the string in one go without the need to explicitly loop in your code, or use other functions such as `map()` and `join()`.

```
encrypt_dict = {'A': 'O', 'B': 'P', 'C': 'J', 'Z': 'Z', '0': 9, '1': 8, '8': 1, '9': 0}
tr_encrypt = {ord(str(k)): ord(str(encrypt_dict[k])) for k in encrypt_dict}
tr_decrypt = {tr_encrypt[k]: k for k in tr_encrypt}

plaintext = 'ABCZ0189'
ciphertext = plaintext.translate(tr_encrypt)
>>> ciphertext
'OPJZ9810'
assert ciphertext.translate(tr_decrypt) == plaintext

plaintext = 'THIS IS test 128'
ciphertext = plaintext.translate(tr_encrypt)
>>> ciphertext
'THIS IS test 821'
assert ciphertext.translate(tr_decrypt) == plaintext
```

The first few lines set up encryption and decryption translation tables in the form required by `str.translate()`. Then it's simply a matter of calling translate on the string to encrypt and decrypt as required.

The second example shows that any character in the string that is not present in the translation table is left unchanged which may or may not be what you want. You can create a translation mapping that covers all expected characters, but that's potentially a lot if you are using unicode.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you want. You can use `string.printable[:61]` where `string.printable` prints all the ASCII characters and `[:61]` takes all characters from index 0 to 61 - which are letters and numbers

```
import string
import random
normla_l=list(string.printable[:61])
new_l=list(string.printable[:61])
random.shuffle(new_l)
see_list={x:y for x,y in zip(normla_l,new_l)}
def change_list(char):
    return see_list.get(char) if char!='' else random.choice(normla_l) 
x=input("Enter string: ")
print(''.join([change_list(char.strip()) for char in x]).strip())
```

Sample

```
Enter string: This string will be encrypted
Xqv7G74HvTxbPv55psIVITzHhg4IN
```